# Avoiding INSUFFICIENT_DATA CloudWatch alarms on SNS notifications

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I have an SNS topic that is published to whenever an SES email bounces.  I have a CloudWatch alarm set up to trigger when a threshold of notifications is crossed over the past hour.

In practice, bounces are rare, and because SNS notifications are only sent when an email bounces, the alarm spends almost its entire time in the `INSUFFICIENT_DATA` state.

Ideally, I'd like for the lack of SNS notifications to be treated as a zero value.  In other monitoring systems (like graphite/grafana) this is consider "null as zero."

Is there any way to treat the (lack of) notifications this way, and keep the alarm out of the insufficient data state?

Answer (score 9):

Amazon SNS does not send metric data to CloudWatch when the value is zero. This results in `INSUFFICIENT_DATA` for Alarms where no emails are send. However, your alarm should work as desired with no change.

The `INSUFFICIENT_DATA` message results from two situations:

- The alarm has **not been in existence** for the measurement period (eg an alarm that calculates the total over a 1-hour period needs to have existed for at least 1 hour).
- There is **no data** within the defined period

If there is at least one data point within the past hour, and the alarm has existed for at least an hour, then the state will be either `OK` or `ALARM`.

**Therefore, you should treat `INSUFFICIENT_DATA` the same as `OK`.** (It is even possible to trigger alarms based on entering the `INSUFFICIENT DATA` state!)

Also, in case you're not already, be sure to use `SUM` rather than `AVERAGE` since your use-case involves looking at the count of messages during a period. My tests show that a `SUM` alarm triggers immediately, whereas `AVERAGE` requires more time.

Comment: Thanks.  I was hoping to avoid the state transitions between `OK` and `INSUFFICIENT_DATA`, but I take from your answer (and my own research) that it's not possible.  Ideally, I'd like the lack of SNS notifications to be treated like 0, not no-data.

Comment: My metric is showing data points within the period (1 minute) and the alarm has been in INSUFFICIENT_DATA mode for days. My statistic is `SampleCount`; not sure if that makes a difference or not...

Comment: Ugh. My problem was that SampleCount doesn't actually count samples but returns <missing> every time (for some reason). Changing to Sum resolved the issue. (My metric produced two samples each with value 1 per period--SampleCount says there is no data).

Answer (score 0):

A silly mistake, but hopefully it's helps someone.

I created an alarm using a template (copied fro the AWS site). The template was for an EC2 Alarm and I wanted to use it for an RDS Alarm. The alarm sat in 'INSUFFICIENT_DATA' state forever until I realize the Dimensions Name value should of been 'DBInstanceIdentifier' for RDS not 'InstanceID' for EC2  ;-)

"StateValue": "INSUFFICIENT_DATA",
            "Dimensions": [
                {
                    "Name": "**InstanceId**",
                    "Value": "database-audit"
                }
            ],

Should of been:

"Dimensions": [
                {
                    "Name": "**DBInstanceIdentifier**",
                    "Value": "database-audit"
                }
            ],